# Twilio - Outgoing call - how to capture touchtone responses

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I want to make a call with Twilio, play an audio message and have the recipient press 1 for yes, press 2 for no. I want to capture this response and, based on the choice, perform some logic server-side.

How can I accomplish this with Java and the Twilio API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is gather the digits entered by the user so you can perform some backend logic right?

All you have to do for that is use the [Gather](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) verb, and return that on your TwiML.

On your webhook, you can return something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <Response>     
  <Gather numDigits = "1" action = "_actionURL" method="POST">
  </Gather>
 </Response>
```

And on _actionUrl (whatever you defined) you can expect those digits to be passed in on the `Digits` parameter.

You can find a sample Java application [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/twiml/record-caller-leave-message) too.